# App server data fetch in debug mode but doesn't work in release mode

Tags: android

I am fetching data from server it is working fine in debug apk but I am trying on generate signed apk, data is not fetching data from server.

Is there any way to get solution?

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

Proguard may be causing that issue. Please check if it is enabled in your app's gradle file.

These lines enables proguard for release build:

```
release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

If yes then you will need to keep some fields.

See this: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

Comment: I need to add minifyEnabled true ? actually i am using minifyEnabled false.

Comment: If minifyEnabled is set to false then it is not the 'proguard' which is causing that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `@Keep` annotation for all your network models (if you or your libs uses reflection). Because proguard obfuscate all classes in signed apk and Gson can`t parse JSON to you model.

**EDIT:**
for example you have class for parse from json (`NetworkResponse.java` class):

```
@Keep
public class NetworkResponse {
   // fields of class...
}
```

Comment: where i need add @keep annotation , i am using retrifit 2 lib for fetching data from server

Comment: Do you use gson?

Comment: Yes i am using gson

Comment: You need to add this annotation in class declaration for each your model. Example `Response.java`: `@Keep public class Response {...`

Comment: If is use getter and setter  ??

Comment: It does not matter.

Comment: the @keep annotation is not required. `@SerializedName` is just fine, cause your parser will still understand that the obfuscated `public int jdiejwdij` maps to the `id` key

Comment: @LokeshGPLoki Did my answer help you?